# Bounds on the eigenvalues of a covariance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

Consider the (symmetric) covariance matrix $\Sigma_{22}(k,k)=
\begin{bmatrix}
    b(0)       & b(1)& b(2) & \cdots & b(k-1) \\
    b(1)      & b(0) & b(1) & \cdots & b(k-2) \\
    \vdots  && \vdots \\
    b(k-1)      & b(k-2)& b(k-3)& \cdots & b(0)
\end{bmatrix},
$

where $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nb(|i-j|)=O(n^{2H})$ and $0<H<1$.  Can we give an estimate of the bounds of the eigenvalues, $\min \lambda_i$ and $\max \lambda_i$? I know that $\sum \lambda_i=trace(\Sigma_{22})=kb(0)$, so $b(0)\leq\max \lambda_i\leq kb(0)$, but can we give a better estimate? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have google two for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm